# Counter in SQL resetting for groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, counting

I'm trying to create a running counter like this

[Calculate a Running Total in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-server/10309947)

But resetting it at the beginning of each month.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Use `PARTITION BY` in the `OVER` clause. If you are using SQL Server 2012+, of course.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir! That was the solution :)